# Sublime Text 3 is not showing Unicode characters correctly under Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unicode, utf-8, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3, unicode characters are not shown correctly. In gedit it works fine. I tried saving the document as UTF-8, Tried setting default encoding to UTF-8 but still its not working. I even tried changing the font. Please check this picture :

[image]

The top word is the correct form. But sublime is showing it differently (like the word in the bottom). How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the rendering logic. Report it to the developers. In the meantime, maybe switch to a different editor?

Comment: WHY in the world would you need to use sublime text for these characters?

Comment: What are these characters? Please include them as text in the question, or specify their Unicode numbers. It seems that the last character is a combining mark and the rendering logic cannot handle it (and shows the mark as a standalone glyph).

Comment: These are Sinhala characters. Im developing a sinhala website. So, for the title and some other parts of the site I need to add these words.

Comment: Yes, but can you paste them as text or provide some other way to unambiguously reproduce the problem you are asking about?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sublime doesn't support Complex Text Layout at all I'm afraid. That means you don't even get proper Arabic or Hebrew, let alone Sinhala.

Hopefully this will be added some day but it's not a straightforward feature. As Sublime is focused on code rather than natural language it might not be amongst the author's priorities.

Comment: do you have a source for this?

Comment: See thread https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=710 on bidi which is a part of complex text layout. Rendering Arabic or Sinhala would also require context-sensitive glyph shaping.

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Preferences > Settings > User**.

Add this setting:

```
"default_encoding" : "utf-8",
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 3 should support many utf-8 locales now.

If Xuwei Khan's answer doesn't work for you, then use this command:

```
iconv -f Windows-1253 -t utf-8 input.txt > output.txt
```

Or replace `Windows-1253` with an an other iso locale suitable for your language needs.