# Sublime Text 2 Unicode Character doesn't showing properly

Tags: unicode, sublimetext2

Using Sublime Text 2 on Windows PC. I checked all the settings like:

- `default_encoding`
- `enable_hexadecimal_encoding`
- `fallback_encoding`
- and even with a perfect Bengali `font_face`

I can't manage to show the Bengali Unicode Characters to show properly. They are broken:
[image: Bengali Texts are broken in Sublime Text 2]
If properly rendered the texts would look like:
[image: Bengali texts from Browser]

I googled about the matter, and found it's not just a Bengali-specific issue - it's global; but the Forum seems offline. Can anybody shed some light on the matter?

Comment: Have you tried using [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3)?

Comment: Sublime doesn't do complex script rendering. Sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317351/sublime-text-3-is-not-showing-unicode-characters-correctly-under-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: @MattDMo sorry, no luck even using Sublime Text 3. :(